# OnClick() on buttons not working after I do something and return back to button's activity

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have debugged and found that the flow of control never reaches the `OnClick()` method in **Main Activity** after I come back from a activity launched from the main activity.

Suspecting this gotta do with 'Paused' or 'Resumed' state.

In other words, 
Main activity be A. and activity launched from A be B.
So, from A i launch and work on B. And when i return to A (using hardware button 'back') then `onClick` function doesnt seem to be called.

For privacy purpose I have removed some code displayed below which will give error if compiled, but in my actual code the activity B and listviews i call run fine .

Please help! :)

My code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity implements Serializable,
        OnClickListener {

    // fetch  data in form of string from the url
    public String InternetData;


     public static ArrayList<String> List;
    public static Boolean hasRanOnce;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialize();
        // begin AsyncTask doInBackground 
        RequestData();
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        hasRanOnce = Boolean.FALSE;

        List = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    private void RequestData() {
            //string is a url, I removed it from here

        GetMethodEx requestObject = new GetMethodEx();
        requestObject.setActivity(this);
        requestObject.execute(string);
    }

    // function called by OnPostExecute of GetMethodEx
    public void BuildNodes() {

        try {
            // create JSON objects  
            rootNode = rootNode.createNode(jObject);

            passList.add(rootNode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected void StartList() {
        // start new activity for publishing the results as a list
        Intent myList = new Intent(this, List.class);
        myList.putExtra("passList", passList);
        hasRanOnce = Boolean.TRUE;
        startActivity(myList);

    }
```

///##where i am facing problem possibly

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Display:
            StartList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: where have you added the onclicklistener ??

Comment: @rs9766 - check at beginning of class, 

public class Main extends Activity implements Serializable,
        OnClickListener {

Comment: Yeah But where have you set the onClickListener to the view example View x=(View)findViewById(R.id.Display); x.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Try this code

  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Intent myList = new Intent(this, List.class);
            myList.putExtra("passList", passList);
            hasRanOnce = Boolean.TRUE;
            startActivity(myList);
                }
            });
```

Comment: your solution is giving me the required outut, and the clicks  are responding now. please explain why it is working like this, but not when defined separately as a member function of the class.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:onClick="Click"
```

put the above code in your xml file and then write the function in your activity 
eg

```
public void Click(View v)
{
// do something 
}
```

or you can do this

```
button=(button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                         }
    });
```

Comment: the second solution is giving the required output.
please explain why it is working like this, but not when defined separately as a member function of the class?

Comment: also in 'share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {'
u meant button i believe.